# MVC 3 [If then else] custom Validation with JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I'm having a problem doing custom validation.

Assuming I have the following class:

```
// begin example
 class vehicle
 {
     prop bool Car { get; set; }
     prop string RegistrationID { get; set; }
     prop int numberOfSeats { get; set; }
 }
// end example
```

I want to have validation that: If the property `Car` is true, then the `numberOfSeats` is required, else the `numberOfSeats` is not required and the corresponding textbox is disabled.

Based on the class, I have a stronglyTyped view where I use the HTML helpers.

I've been reading several articles about validations, including this [link](http://tdryan.blogspot.com/2010/12/aspnet-mvc-3-custom-validation.html) but cannot find the solution.

To make the above validation, it is best to create a custom control, since I have to validate and depend on the property `Car`. I disable and enable a textbox (property `numberOfSeats`) ?

Answer (score 0):

The project at http://foolproof.codeplex.com/ includes a `[RequiredIfTrue]` custom validator which seems to fit what you're looking for. You'd have to disable/enable the textbox yourself, though.